# "Create an Eclipse plug-in" tutorial: The hierarchy of the type SampleView is inconsistent

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I’m currently working through the “Create an Eclipse plug-in” tutorial, but I’m stuck at the following stage:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Se4.jpg)

The last thing I did was create a Java class for the “Hello World!” View for the extension org.eclipse.ui.views. However, I’m getting the error “The hierarchy of the type SampleView is inconsistent.”

From what I’ve read, this error is often caused by the .jar file of the inherited class (in this case, ViewPart) not being on the build path of the project.

However, the target platform does include the org.eclipse.ui.views plugin (in which the org.eclipse.ui.views.jar file should be contained):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnnEZ.jpg)

Any help with this would be appreciated!

UPDATE: here are the contents of...

plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            id="com.example.helloworld.commands.category"
            name="Sample Category">
      </category>
      <command
            categoryId="com.example.helloworld.commands.category"
            name="Display Hello World"
            id="com.example.helloworld.commands.sampleCommand">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="com.example.helloworld.handlers.SampleHandler"
            commandId="com.example.helloworld.commands.sampleCommand">
      </handler>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="com.example.helloworld.commands.sampleCommand"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
            sequence="M1+6">
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               id="com.example.helloworld.menus.sampleMenu"
               label="Sample Menu"
               mnemonic="M">
            <command
                  commandId="com.example.helloworld.commands.sampleCommand"
                  id="com.example.helloworld.menus.sampleCommand"
                  mnemonic="S">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
         <toolbar
               id="com.example.helloworld.toolbars.sampleToolbar">
            <command
                  id="com.example.helloworld.toolbars.sampleCommand"
                  commandId="com.example.helloworld.commands.sampleCommand"
                  icon="icons/sample.png"
                  tooltip="Say hello world">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <category
            id="com.example.helloworld.view.helloworldcategory"
            name="Hello World!">
      </category>
      <view
            category="com.example.helloworld.view.helloworldcategory"
            class="com.example.helloworld.view.SampleView"
            id="com.example.helloworld.view.helloworldview"
            name="Hello World!"
            restorable="true">
      </view>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Helloworld
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.helloworld;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: EXAMPLE
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui
Automatic-Module-Name: com.example.helloworld
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-17
```

Comment: For a start save the 'com.sample.helloworld' plugin.xml/MANIFEST.MF edit - lots of things are not set up until you save the file. If that doesn't help show us the contents of the MANIFEST.MF and plugin.xml

Comment: And what the Type Hierarchy view makes of your type--it might help you figure out where it becomes "inconsistent".

Comment: @greg-449 see update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to also require the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` plug-in in the MANIFEST.MF

So the `Require-Bundle` part of the manifest should be:

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui
```

After doing this you may still have an error showing for the view part but now it will be about not implementing the `createPartControl` and `setFocus` methods. Quick fix will deal with that adding something like:

```java
  @Override
  public void createPartControl(Composite parent)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
  }

  @Override
  public void setFocus()
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
  }
```